# How to Cache a Script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, caching, yii

In my application, there is a view `Upload.php`

I want to cache the script which is responsible for generating file list on the page, as it is very much static and not going to change often.

Code:

```
<!-- DOWNLOAD TEMPLATE -->      
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade" search-name="{%=file.name%}">
    {% if (file.error) { %}
        <td class="name">
            <span class="delete"><input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="nomargin"></span>
            <span >{%=file.name%}</span>
        </td>
        <td class="size right"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
    {% } else { %}
        <td class="name">
        <span class="delete"><input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="nomargin"></span>

        {% if (file.status_code == 2 || file.status_code == 3) { %}                             

            <!-- TRACE IN PROCESSED / PARTIALLY PROCESSED STATE -->

            <span class="clickcursor {% if (!file.shared_in) { %} filename {% } %}" title="Click here to Analyze" data-file="{%=file.name%}"
            data-target="[tracefile]" data-id="{%=file.id%}"
            data-idtarget="[trace_id]" data-formid="dashboard">
            {%=file.name%}
            </span>

            <!-- SHARED IN / SHARED OUT ICON -->

            {% if (file.shared_in) { %}
                <span class="shared-by" title="Shared by {%=file.shared_by%}">&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="<?php echo $baseURL
                ?>/wizshark/img/shared.png"/></span>
            {% } %}
            {% if (file.shared_out) { %}
                <span class="shared-with" title="Shared with {%=file.shared_with%}">&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="<?php echo $baseURL
                ?>/wizshark/img/shared.png"/></span>
            {% } %}

            <!-- NOTES EMPTY / NOTES FILLED ICON -->

            {% if (file.notes == '') { %}
                <span class="notes empty clickcursor" title="Add notes" style="display:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="<?php echo $baseURL
                ?>/wizshark/img/notes_empty.png"/></span>
            {% } else { %}
                <span class="notes clickcursor" title="View notes">&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="<?php echo $baseURL
                ?>/wizshark/img/notes_filled.png"/></span>
            {% } %}
        {% } else { %}
```

So as you can see, a lot of data binding is in use here, irrespective of that, i would like to save this whole script/template in cache, is there a way i could achieve it?
By any framework, or technique of memorization here..

Answer (score 0):

You can use CAssetManager to publish any type of file to the assets folder;

Refer to publish function here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager#publish-detail

Once published you can load the script in your view using the returned url of publish()